# Union error in one select but I still want the results

Tags: mysql, select, union

I am doing a large union select and all of the union selects will retrieve a result except for one. One of them has a collation error. For example

```
SELECT word FROM words WHERE english = 'hello'
UNION
SELECT word FROM words WHERE english = 'no'
UNION
SELECT word FROM words WHERE english = 'пыук';
```

The last one would produce a collation error and therefore the whole select fails. Is there a way that I can include the select for the one that will return the error while still getting the results for the rest of them?

Comment: *The last one would produce a collation error* Always provide complete and unchanged error message.

Comment: `SELECT word FROM words WHERE english = 'пыук' COLLATE {correct collation}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this would be to `CONVERT()` the collation of the string you’re looking up to the collation of the column:

```
SELECT word FROM words WHERE english = CONVERT('пыук' USING utf8);
```

**Side Note**: Be sure to change `utf8` to the same collation as your `english` column.

This is suboptimal, but it will do what you need.